# Retrofit 2.0 beta1: how to post raw String body

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am looking for some way to post request with raw body with new Retrofit 2.0b1. Something like this:

```
@POST("/token")
Observable<TokenResponse> getToken(@Body String body);
```

As far as I understand, there should be some kind of strait "to-string" converter, but it is not clear to me yet how it works.

There were ways to make it happen in 1.9 with TypedInput, but it does not help in 2.0 anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be registering a converter for your `Type` when you are building your `Retrofit` using `addConverter(type, converter)`.

`Converter<T>` in 2.0 uses similar approach using old Converter in 1.x version.

Your `StringConverter` should be something like this:

```
public class StringConverter implements Converter<Object>{


    @Override
    public String fromBody(ResponseBody body) throws IOException {
        return ByteString.read(body.byteStream(), (int) body.contentLength()).utf8();
    }

    @Override
    public RequestBody toBody(Object value) {
        return RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), value.toString());
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. `ByteString` is from Okio library.
2. Mind the `Charset` in your `MediaType`

Comment: I have just found how to do it as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 46):

In Retrofit 2 you can use `RequestBody` and `ResponseBody` to post a body to server using `String` data and read from server's response body as `String`.

First you need to declare a method in your RetrofitService:

```
interface RetrofitService {
    @POST("path")
    Call<ResponseBody> update(@Body RequestBody requestBody);
}
```

Next you need to create a `RequestBody` and `Call` object:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://somedomain.com").build();
RetrofitService retrofitService = retrofit.create(RetrofitService.class);

String strRequestBody = "body";
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),strRequestBody);
Call<ResponseBody> call = retrofitService.update(requestBody);
```

And finally make a request and read response body as `String`:

```
try {
    Response<ResponseBody> response = call.execute();
    if (response.isSuccess()) {
        String strResponseBody = response.body().string();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Nice solution

Comment: This should be the valid answer.

Comment: Brilliant this was exactly what I needed `RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), strRequestBody);`

Comment: Just a quick heads up, the create-method is now deprecated, but it seems the only change you need to do, is switch the parameter order. And then its not deprecated anymore.