# Cannot send Soap Request as String using Retrofit 2.0

Tags: soap, retrofit

I tried sending Soap Request as String using Retrofit 2.0 but it always add myrequestString .
Do you know how to send an String SoapUI format via Retrofit 2.0?

Here is my code:
**MyService.java:**

```
@Headers({
            "Content-Type: text/xml"
    })
    @POST
    Call<ResponseBody> loadRepo(@Url String url,@Body String body);
```

String to send request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:ValidateLink>
         <Request>
...
```

Request actual:

```
<string>&lt;?xml version=&apos;1.0&apos; encoding=&apos;UTF-8&apos; standalone=&apos;yes&apos; ?&gt;&lt;soapenv:Envelope xmlns:au
...
;/soapenv:Body&gt;&lt;/soapenv:Envelope&gt;</string>
```

Request Expected:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <web:ValidateLink>
             <Request>
```

Comment: You  need to provide `StringConverter`. See details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656358/retrofit-2-0-beta1-how-to-post-raw-string-body/32656717#32656717

Comment: Thanks Nikola, But I want it requests as raw file (Soap), not String(retrofit auto add <string>). Do you know how to force retrofit know it a soap data?