# Using retrofit with XML data

Tags: android, xml, retrofit, retrofit2

I would like to call an API (@POST) who works with XML data. And i litteraly don't know how to send it '-'. I learnt how do to with Json, but different with XML

I search for like 3/4 days and i couldn't find any solution that fit for me :/

Here is the request i need to send :

```
<qosFeatureData xmlns:qos="urn:oma:xml:rest:netapi:qos:1">
<clientCorrelator>v1234</clientCorrelator>
<predefinedQosFeatureId>Pred_Coca</predefinedQosFeatureId>
<media>
    <mediaNumber>1</mediaNumber>
    <mediaType>Other</mediaType>
    <ipFlow>
        <flowNumber>1</flowNumber>
        <flowDescription>
                <direction>Downlink</direction>
                <protocol>6</protocol>
                <otherPartyIpAddress>
                <ipV4Address>X.X.X.X</ipV4Address>
            </otherPartyIpAddress>
                <otherPartyPortNumber>
                <port>XX</port>
                </otherPartyPortNumber>
                <userIpAddress>
                <ipV4Address>Y.Y.Y.Y</ipV4Address>    ?????
                </userIpAddress>
        </flowDescription>
        <flowDescription>
                <direction>Uplink</direction>
                <protocol>6</protocol>
                <otherPartyIpAddress>
                <ipV4Address>X.X.X.X</ipV4Address>
                </otherPartyIpAddress>
                <otherPartyPortNumber>
                <port>XX</port>
                </otherPartyPortNumber>
                <userIpAddress>
                <ipV4Address>Y.Y.Y.Y</ipV4Address>    ?????
                </userIpAddress>
        </flowDescription>
        <flowStatus>Enabled</flowStatus>
    </ipFlow>
    <flowStatus>Enabled</flowStatus>
</media>
```

I already set up the code for the call "Post" (with nothing in it) and i got a response (not a good response : 500, but i think it's because of my data who are not sent)

**Here is my interface code**

```
public interface ApiHttpPost {

@Headers({"Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8"})
@POST("confidential")
Call<qosFeature> getqosFeature (@Header("Authorization") String authHeader);
```

}

**Here my main activity**

```
private void AppelHttpPost() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("CONFIDENTIAL")
            .client(getUnsafeOkHttpClient())
            .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    ApiHttpPost service = retrofit.create(ApiHttpPost.class);

    String userName = "CONFIDENTIAL";
    String passWord = "CONFIDENTIAL";
    String base = userName + ":" + passWord;

    String authHeader = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(base.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

    Call<qosFeature> qosFeatureCall = service.getqosFeature(authHeader);

    qosFeatureCall.enqueue(new Callback<qosFeature>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<qosFeature> call, Response<qosFeature> response) {
            int statusCode = response.code();
            qosFeature qosFeature = response.body();
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + statusCode);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<qosFeature> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Thx for your help :s

EDIT : i come back to require your help again, the solution proposed by Potapov Anton doesn't really work in my case. On Android studio, in debug mode i see something good ! (Screeshot)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJSl9.png)

But when i look on Wireshark it's not good, there is the String /String that i don't want + the xml doesn't look well (Screenshot)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idGFb.png)

So any other idea to send xml data ? :x Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just send your XML as a text, don't you?

```
public interface ApiHttpPost {

@Headers({"Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8"})
@POST("confidential")
Call<qosFeature> getqosFeature (@Header("Authorization") String authHeader, @Body String body);
}
```

Comment: But don't i need to creat a class "body" and call it to be able to use it here ?

Comment: You don't need to create any more classes. Just pass it as a string into body param. It has type String.

Comment: So in my main activity i need to add something like that :
   String body = "all the xml resquest here"
And call it in : service.getqosFeature(authHeader, body)

Right ?

Comment: Yes, sir. Hope that helped.

Comment: Ok thx bruh, now i'll try to find how to creat the model answer (like the pojo for Gson)

Comment: i've update my message cause your method work but doesn't works for me :x (dunno if you understood xD) if you have any other idea thx :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok guys i found the exact solution of my problem.

The problem with the solution above was, sending the xml data as a String type, that what i don't want.

So i found this answer on another thread, i apply it and it worked '-' (creating an object with the type application/xml)

here the thread : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33738730/8342943