# 500 error using Skyscanner API with Kotlin and Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I want to connect to the Skyscanner API, using Kotlin and Retrofit. https://rapidapi.com/skyscanner/api/skyscanner-flight-search

When attempting to POST the 'create session' call, I get a 500 error, but the logs aren't giving a specific reason. I can only assume that my post data isn't being formatted correctly, but I'm using Retrofit with GSon to handle this for me.

One clue, is that in their Java sample code, they pass the form data in the following format: **"inboundDate=2019-09-10&children=0&adults=1"** whereas after GSon convertion from my sessionObject class, my data is in the format **{"adults":1,"country":"GB","outboundDate":"2020-01-06"}** - I'm unsure how, using Retrofit, I can pass my data in that format, and whether that's the issue causing the 500.

Here are some code snippets:

```
// my object for posting data
class SessionBody {

    @SerializedName("country")
    var country: String = ""
    @SerializedName("currency")
    var currency: String = ""
    ...etc...

// my interface
@Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@POST("pricing/v1.0/")
fun postUser(@Body sessionBody: SessionBody): Call<Void>


// my connector class
val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(Interceptor { chain ->
    val original = chain.request()
    val request = original.newBuilder()
        .header("X-RapidAPI-Host", "skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-   v1.p.rapidapi.com")
        .header("X-RapidAPI-Key", "...my key here...")
        .method(original.method(), original.body())
        .build()
    return@Interceptor chain.proceed(request)
})
.addInterceptor(interceptor)
.connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.build()

val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl(BASE_URL)
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().create()))
.client(client)
.build()

val api = retrofit.create(TravelEzyApi::class.java)
val call = api.postUser(sessionBody)
```

And here is the output from the logs...

```
D/OkHttp: --> POST https://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com/apiservices/pricing/v1.0/
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 142
X-RapidAPI-Host: skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com
X-RapidAPI-Key: ... my key here ...
{"adults":1,"country":"GB","currency":"GBP","destinationPlace":"BKK-sky","locale":"en-GB","originPlace":"LHR-sky","outboundDate":"2020-01-06"}
--> END POST (142-byte body)
D/OkHttp: <-- 500 Internal Server Error 
D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 22 Oct 2019 10:48:44 GMT
Server: RapidAPI-1.0.32
X-RapidAPI-Region: AWS - eu-west-1
X-RapidAPI-Version: 1.0.32
Content-Length: 2
Connection: keep-alive
{}
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (2-byte body)
```

Any help or clues greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey Neil, I'm not familiar with Kotlin, but are you sending the body as form data? Errors starting with 5 generally mean "server error, not your fault". Is it possible something's going wrong outside of your code?

Comment: Ok, as I suspected, it was the format of the data being sent that was the problem. The server was expecting the body to contain a comma separated list, rather than the JSON I was sending. The solution here helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656358/retrofit-2-0-beta1-how-to-post-raw-string-body

Answer (score 0):

The 500 Status code indicates that the server has encountered a situation it does not know how to handle.

This should work fine by now. You can always write to the RapidAPI support team if the error still persists at support@rapidapi.com